# flask add a new row based on id of other tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have two tables, named projects and actions and every project contain several action

```
class Projet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nom_projet = db.Column(db.String(100))    
    description_projet = db.Column(db.String(800))                         
    date_affectation = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)                              
    statut_projet = db.Column(db.String(100))

    admin_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('admins.id'))

    actions = db.relationship('Action', backref='projet',
                                lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Projet: {}>'.format(self.id)

class Action(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'  
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    projet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projets.id'))   
    description =  db.Column(db.String(1000))                        
    statut_action = db.Column(db.String(100))                               
    date_action =  db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False) 
    date_execution = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = True) 
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Action: {}>'.format(self.id)
```

my problem is, I need to create a new action based on an existing project as shown in image,
[image]
I need to click on add button and he must redirect me to action form with the name of project auto-selected, and  I entre the action details.

this is my first code to add action:

```
@auth.route('/action/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_action():
    form = ActionForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        action = Action(
            projet = form.projet.data,
            description = form.description.data,
            statut_action = form.statut_action.data,
            date_action = form.date_action.data,
            date_execution = form.date_execution.data
        )
        try:
            db.session.add(action)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('You have successfully added a new action.')
        except:
            flash('Error: action name already exists.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.list_projets'))
    return render_template('admin/actions/action.html', action="Add", form=form,
                           title="ADD ACTION")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Update the URL to include project_id as path param: ex: `/project/1/actions/add` is meant to load a page with new action form for project with id 1
2. Update the links to add new action in the previous page(as shown in the screenshot) as per step 1
3. Remove `project` field from `ActionForm` as it is handled using path param
4. Update "new action form" page to show product name coming in `product_name` variable

Try,

```
@auth.route('/project/<project_id>/action/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_action(project_id):
    form = ActionForm()
    project = Project.query.get(project_id)
    if not project:
        flash('Error: invalid project')
        abort(404)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        action = Action(
            project = project,
            description = form.description.data,
            statut_action = form.statut_action.data,
            date_action = form.date_action.data,
            date_execution = form.date_execution.data
        )
        try:
            db.session.add(action)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('You have successfully added a new action.')
        except:
            flash('Error: action name already exists.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.list_projets'))
    return render_template('admin/actions/action.html', action="Add", form=form,
                           title="ADD ACTION", project_name=project.name)
```